# How do I remove a sticker in Trello?

Tags: trello, trello-cards

How do I remove stickers from cards in [Trello](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trello)?

Adding stickers in Trello is easy enough. Just drag them over from the stickers at the right:

[image: Opening the stickers menu item]

[image: Stickers menu item and a card where a sticker has been added to]

However, how can a sticker be removed again?

Comment: How to remove stickers in Trello is not obvious **at all**. I found the solution while writing the question.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It is a three-step process to remove a sticker:

1. Hover the mouse in the card so the pencil in the upper-right corner appears (in this example, for the second card that has the sticker):

   [image: Hovering the mouse cursor in a Trello card]
2. Left click on the pencil and click on the sticker:

   [image: Trello card in edit mode]
3. The result is:

   [image: Trello sticker in edit mode]
4. Click on *Remove*. The sticker is now gone, regardless of whether *Save* is pressed or not.

Comment: Someone didn't think so much over this one. There should have been a way of removing the sticker analogous to adding a sticker.

Answer (score 0):

As of July 2019, the above steps didn't quite work for me. What I had to do was:

1. Hover over the sticker
2. Enter edit mode (press "e" on the keyboard)
3. Left-Click the sticker
4. Click "Remove" on the pop-up menus

Simply hovering and clicking the "Remove" appears to be ignored.